# Ambigous use of section

Tags: swift, tableview, swift3, xcode8

I have a strange issue, in all methods that use tableView have the error. I can't use indexPath. Any ideas. ??

```
 import UIKit
 import GoogleMaps
 import GooglePlaces

 class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate,
    GMSMapViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,
    UITableViewDelegate {
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you cmd-click on indexPath (or IndexPath) do you get multiple definitions?

Comment: if I click to IndexPath, I go to Foundation->IndexPath

Comment: If I click to indexPath nothing happened

Comment: Try replacing `IndexPath` with `Foundation.IndexPath`  or even `NSIndexPath`.

Comment: Matt, can you please add this to a solution.     let index = indexPath as NSIndexPath, and the use índex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use **indexPath**     follow the next code:

```
 let index = indexPath as NSIndexPath
 let row = índex.row
```

I dont know why the compiler get confused .